# Select Objects related in third table

Tags: django, django-orm

Say I have the models

```
class A(models.Model):

class B(models.Model):
   
class C(models.model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

class D(models.Model):
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

What would a ORM query look like to select all Bs that are related to C's that are related to a specific A through table D?

Comment: `B.objects.filter(c__d__a=specific_a_obj)`

Comment: @IainShelvington but B has no Foreign key on C and C has no Foreign key on D

Comment: The reverse relationship can be followed backwards, using the name of the model if no `related_name` argument is provided to the ForeignKey, or using the `related_name` from the ForeignKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the comment on your post you can use the autogenerated [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). But it never hurts to set it yourself.

```py
class C(models.model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="c")

class D(models.Model):
    c = models.ForeignKey(C, related_name="d")
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="d")
```

Then:

`B.objects.filter(c__d__a=specific_a_obj).distinct()`

Comment: that's a good solution. Is there any way the other way round?

Answer (score -1):

```
    class C (models.Model):
        b = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='c_related')
```

final query:

```
    c_ids = D.objects.values_list(
            'c__id', flat=True).filter(a__id="specific A object id palced here")

    query = B.objects.filter(c_related__id__in=c_ids).distinct()
```

Comment: This is a very complex way of reaching the solution